# Discrete Structures question. Don't know how to start really rusty, please explain like I'm five.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1. Prove the following identity on languages A, B:  (A ∪ B)* = (A*B*)*
2. For string x, the reversal of x, denoted $x^R$, is defined as , if x= $\varepsilon$; and as  $x_n$ $x_2$ $x_1$, if x= $x_1$ $x_2$...$x_n$.  For language A, the reversal of A, denoted $A^R$, is defined to be
   $A^R$  = { $x^R$   for all x in A }.
   Determine if the following equation is true for all languages A or not.  Present a proof or a counterexample: ($A^R$)* = $(A*)^R$

I still don't really understand what the star symbol means and how that affects the equations.

Comment: $X^\ast$ is the set of all finite strings made of elements from $X$.

Comment: It’s not true in general that $(A\cup B)^*=(AB)^*$. Let $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$; then $(A\cup B)^*=\{0,1\}^*$ is the set of all finite sequences of zeroes and ones, so it contains the word $0$. $(AB)^*$, however, is $(01)^*$, whose elements are $\epsilon,01,0101,010101$, and so on, the set of all finite words formed by concatenating $0$ or more copies of $01$, which clearly does **not** contain the word $0$.